# Exposing property to class using declare module typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

Supposed I have a class

```
export class Member {
  // properties

  // and methods
}
```

and I want to expose the `output` on `Member class`

```
declare module '@/lib/member' {
  interface Member {
    output: OutputInterface
  }
}
```

I can successfully use the `output` via

```
export class Member {
  sampleMethod(name: string) {
      this.output.getName(name)
  }
}
```

However I'm getting an `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getName' of undefined` and when I

```
 console.log(this.output) // undefined
```

but when I tried to expose it in vue I used

```
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    output: OutputInterface
  }
}
```

I can get the output correct and Im not getting any `undefined errors`

any idea where did I get wrong? I'm fairly new to typescript.

Comment: Please quote the **exactly** error message when asking for help with errors, using copy and paste (don't retype them, it's too easy to introduce typos).

Comment: Please show more of the code where you're having trouble, in particular how `this.output` is initialized. It sounds like you never assign anything to `this.output` in the `Member` constructor (something TypeScript should be complaining about). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally with a link to the TypeScript playground containing the same code as the code in the question and demonstrating the problem. (Please **don't** just put the code in the TypeScript playground; it needs to be in the question as well.) Then maybe we can help! :-)